# Popup "An assistive technology like a screen reader may be running on your machine."

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

Out of the blue I am getting the popup below since a couple of days. I haven't installed any app of the sort (at least not on my own will), so I'm afraid this might be sign of malware. Is it possible to determine which process is triggering this behavior on Acrobat (Pro DC)? Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: Some people already flagged this on Adobe's forum but there was no response...
https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader/pop-up-message-when-opening-pdf-attached-screenshot/m-p/11459200